# Factory girl has_many with different attributes on the associated models?

Tags: ruby, tdd, factory-bot

I'm trying to figure out how to create a factory **product** that has_many **styles**, and I need those **style** factories to have at least one different attribute each (other than id).

I've tried using create_list to generate the associated factories and then update an attribute on one of them:

```
after(:create) do |product|
  products = create_list(:style, 2, product: product, color: 'Black')
  products[0].update_attribute(:color, 'Blue').save!
end
```

First off, this method isn't working. Even if it were, it isn't very elegant. Is there any way to create a list of associations with different attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a block to `create_list`. I've never had to do this, but here is an example from [the spec:](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/spec/acceptance/create_list_spec.rb)

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 20, title: "The Listing of the Block") do |post|
  post.position = post.id
end
```

So maybe you could do something like:

```
colors = ["red", "blue"]

after(:create) do |product|
  create_list(:style, 2, product: product) do |style|
    style.color = colors.pop #first style color will be "blue"
  end
end
```